# Html5 notification(load particular div element to notification body)

Tags: html, html5-notifications

I'm try to use html5 notification,now i'm strggle to load html element into notifications body

Below code I've tried

```
let string = document.getElementById('map')
let myNotification = new Notification('Incomming calls', {
                    body: string.innerHTML
                }).addEventListener('click',function(){
                    console.log('Notification clicked' + message)
                })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if notification works for the browser you are using as test, better still check check this [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/body) also. 
Then you need to be more specific about what the issue is, is there an error message or an output you don't like for us to help you better

Comment: my question is need load html content in notification body